# Process Debug Manager (PDM) security issues

Tags: c#, c++, com, activex, clearscript

I have an issue with all computers in AD:

I'm getting this error after creating VBScriptEngine with debugging flag:
either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid.

```
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070542)
```

The problem is around this line:

```
processDebugManager.AddApplication(debugApplication, out debugApplicationCookie))
```

where processDebugManager is COM:

```
{78A51822-51F4-11D0-8F20-00805F2CD064} [IProcessDebugManager]
```

Impersonation is enabled in the local politics.

Any ideas which restriction could it be?

Comment: Recommend better justifying the C++ tag. Perhaps C++-cli is more fitting?

Comment: Any error starting with 0x8 is a null pointer.  It could be due to access privileges, or trying to access un-managed memory from the c# application.  It looks like it may be a cookie issue and the user don't have the cookie loaded in their cookie folder.  May be an expired cookie.  I would try to clear all cookies from the IE and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to add a solution. This error means that we have installed the mdm (Machine Debug Manager) from VS2002 (which is not used anymore). To fix it we should perform the following steps:

1. Disable MDM service
2. Open system services window:

   > click "Start" -> then type "services" and select it (or find this console via "Control Panel" -> "Administrative Tools"):
3. Click right mouse click on " Machine Debug Manager" and open "Properties"
   Stop the service (click the stop button) and disable it (change the status Type)
4. Reregister system DCOM MDM
   Open cmd as an Administrator:

   > click "Start" -> type "cmd" -> right mouse click -> "Run As Administrator"
   >   Register the server:
   >   WIN 32 (x86): type the command:
   >   mdm.exe /regserver

   WIN 64 (x64): type the following (we have to change the directory to SysWOW64):

   > cd ..\SysWOW64
   >   mdm.exe /regserver

Restart the computer.

If you get access issues, please check DCOM permissions

> (Run -> "dcomcnfg" -> Find "Machine Debug Manager")
>   Go to: "Component Services" -> "Computers" -> "My Computer" -> "DCOM Config" -> "Machine Debug Manager"
>   Right mouse click -> select "Properties"

Open the "Security" tab and recheck permissions. Try to add everyone (or someone special) to understand that it's a permission issue.

The issue I have described here (with images): https://www.zaptest.com/forum/zaptest-best-practices/4057-impersonation-level-is-invalid-0x80070542